# OCaml -- return a list containing the tails of that list

Tags: ocaml

For `[1;2;3;4;5]`, I want to return `[[1;2;3;4;5];[2;3;4;5];[3;4;5;];[4;5];[5];[]]`

I'm trying to use the List library but I'm unsure how to.  So far, I know I have to use List.tl to get the list without the first element

```
let rec tailsoflist (l : 'a list) : 'a list list =
  match l with
      [] -> [[]]
    | x::xs -> l::(tails xs)
```

I did this recursively but now I want to just use the list library without using recursion.

```
let tails (l : 'a list) : 'a list list
```

EDIT: Sorry guys, what I specified for the function to return is incorrect. Just updated it with the correct output.

Comment: There is no function in module `List` that will present the tails of a list `l` to the function you pass it, so you cannot have "the tails of `l`". You can have lists that are structurally equivalent to the tails of `l` if you accept to build new versions of them, for instance with `List.fold_right`.

Comment: Note that your example solution to the problem you pose is incorrect according to your question, e.g. `[1..4]` is not a tail of `[1..5]`. Are you sure you didn't mean `[2..5]` etc.?

Comment: @Pascal: It is not necessary to forgo sharing of the tails: simply thread the original list as part of the `fold`.

Answer (score 4):

As I said in the comment, these are not the tails of `l` but copies of the tails of `l`:

```
# let tails l = List.fold_right (fun e acc -> (e::(List.hd acc))::acc) l [[]] ;;
val tails : 'a list -> 'a list list = <fun>
# tails [1; 2; 3; 4] ;;- : int list list = [[1; 2; 3; 4]; [2; 3; 4]; [3; 4]; [4]; []]
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain to me what the function is doing?  How does the acc work, etc.

Comment: `fold_right` applies the accumulator to the function with the element in the list from right to left. Each call creates a new 'tail', and the next 'tail' is the previous (`List.hd acc`) with the current element (`e`) appended. From [] append 4, from [4] append 3, from [3;4] append 2, ...

Answer (score 4):

There is no good way to write that function in terms of the built-in functions.

The answer you give in your question is fine but it would be more idiomatic to not annotate the types and use `function`:

```
let rec tails = function
  | [] -> [[]]
  | _::xs' as xs -> xs::tails xs'
```

Other languages, like F#, provide a `List.unfold` function that `tails` can be written in terms of.

Comment: It is perfectly possible to write `tails` solely in terms of built-in functions.

Comment: see my answer to this question.

Answer (score 3):

Ah, the old trick to accumulate on the original list to cast `tails` as a catamorphism. This is done without explicit recursion using just functions on the `List` module:

```
let tails l = List.rev ( [] :: snd (List.fold_right
    (fun _ (t,ts) -> List.tl t, t::ts) l (l, [])) )
```

It produces the tails as you expect:

```
# tails [1;2;3;4;5];;
- : int list list = [[1; 2; 3; 4; 5]; [2; 3; 4; 5]; [3; 4; 5]; [4; 5]; [5]; []]
```

and the tails are the *actual* structural tails of the input list, so that `List.tl l == List.hd (List.tl (tails l))`.

Comment: +1 for being a valid counter example to my claim, even if it is darn ugly!

Comment: Proper tails can be more succinctly expressed as `let tails l = snd (List.fold_right (fun _ (t,ts) -> List.tl t, ts @ [t]) l (l, []))` though. This formulation is [Gibbons's](http://www.comlab.ox.ac.uk/publications/publication2330-abstract.html).

Answer (score 1):

"Without using recursion"... why ? Recursion is a useful tool, even outside the `List` library.

```
let rec suffixes = function
| [] -> [[]]
| hd::tl as suff -> suff :: suffixes tl
```

Your function (which doesn't compile because you use `tails` instead of `tailsoflist`) returns the list of suffixes of a list. Due to the list structure, it's easier to compute than the prefixes.

You can express the prefixes from the suffixes :

```
let prefixes li = List.map List.rev (suffixes (List.rev li));;
```

You could do a direct version using an accumulator:

```
let prefixes li =
  let rec pref acc = function
    | [] -> List.rev acc :: []
    | hd::tl -> List.rev acc :: pref (hd :: acc) tl
  in pref [] li
```

and express it using `List.fold_left` if you want to avoid recursion, but this is convoluted so you should prefer the direct version in my opinion:

```
let prefixes li =
  let acc, res =
    List.fold_left
      (fun (acc, res) e -> (e :: acc), (List.rev acc :: res))
      ([], []) li in
  List.rev acc :: res
```

Finally, it is possible to destroy your brain with a version using continuations, but I don't remember the exact code. Roughly, the continuation is equivalent to the "accumulator" of the direct version.